# Obter MAC Address da máquina cliente da aplicação

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

Gostaria de saber a melhor forma de obter o MAC Address do cliente da minha aplicação Asp.Net Web Forms. Como é uma informação de baixo nível, creio que não seja tão simples como parece.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não é possível obter essa informação, uma vez que nem o asp.net tem acesso à essa informação da maquina do cliente nem o Javascript, pois ela não é trafegada como parte do protocolo Http.

A única maneira de obter essa informação seria através de um componente ActiveX ou Java applet que precisaria ser instalado na máquina do cliente e as devidas configurações de segurança aplicadas.

Comment: Então no meu caso a solução será criar um Applet já que usando ActiveX funcionaria apenas no Internet Explorer.

Comment: Se voce quer obter o Mac Address do cliente por motivos de autenticaçao, voce pode usar por exemplo um cookie com algum identificador unico (tipo GUID) para isso. Seria mais leve que criar um applet.

Comment: A minha intenção em obter o Mac Address é para criar um Log em que serão armazenados dados da máquina do cliente na hora do login.

Answer (score 2):

Caso seus clientes estejam na mesma LAN que você (por exemplo, em uma intranet), pode ser que seus endereços MAC estejam presentes na tabela ARP do roteador.

Em um ambiente Windows, você pode checar a tabela ARP via comando `ARP -a`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A classe `System.Diagnostics.Process` permite que você execute um processo em seu servidor;  opcionalmente, você pode redirecionar o conteúdo gerado para um stream de texto (via `StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true`).

A função abaixo executa os passos descritos para obter o MAC Address a partir de um endereço IP:

```
public string GetMacAddress(string ipAddress)
    {
        string macAddress = string.Empty;
        System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "arp";
        pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-a " + ipAddress;
        pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
          pProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        pProcess.Start();
        string strOutput = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string[] substrings = strOutput.Split('-');
        if (substrings.Length >= 8)
        {
           macAddress = substrings[3].Substring(Math.Max(0, substrings[3].Length - 2)) + "-" + substrings[4] + "-" + substrings[5] + "-" + substrings[6] + "-" + substrings[7] + "-" +
                  substrings[8].Substring(0, 2);
            return macAddress;
        }

        else
        {
            return "not found";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mas a minha aplicação é extranet, preciso do Mac Address para fins de Log.

Comment: Como não foi mencionado no post original eu imaginei que este seria um cenário possível, @William. De qualquer maneira irei deixar a resposta aqui - talvez ela seja útil a alguém no futuro.

Answer (score 2):

Amigos, por erro meu não percebi que se tratava de uma aplicação WEB.

Segue a solução em javascript para listar os endereços MAC, contudo ela utiliza um ActiveX e com isso só funcionará no IE. Vou procurar para você se há alguma solução multi-navegadores.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Getting MAC Address From Javascript(IE Only)</title>

    <script language="javascript">
    function showMacAddress(){

        var obj = new ActiveXObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
        var s = obj.ConnectServer(".");
        var properties = s.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
        var e = new Enumerator (properties);


        var output;
        output='<table border="0" cellPadding="5px" cellSpacing="1px" bgColor="#CCCCCC">';
        output=output + '<tr bgColor="#EAEAEA"><td>Caption</td><td>MACAddress</td></tr>';
        while(!e.atEnd())

        {
            e.moveNext();
            var p = e.item ();
            if(!p) continue;
            output=output + '<tr bgColor="#FFFFFF">';
            output=output + '<td>' + p.Caption; + '</td>';
            output=output + '<td>' + p.MACAddress + '</td>';
            output=output + '</tr>';
        }

        output=output + '</table>';
        document.getElementById("box").innerHTML=output;
    }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Show MAC Address" onclick="showMacAddress()" />

        <div id="box">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```