# É possível obter algum valor do browser que identifique a máquina do usuário?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, segurança, navegador-de-internet

**Problema**

Estou pesquisando alguma forma de identificar e validar estações de trabalho, e gostaria de obter algum valor da máquina que não seja mutável, como o IP que pode mudar.

Tentei obter o **MAC address**, mas não parece ser possível por questões de segurança dos browsers (Como mencionado [nesta pergunta aqui mesmo no SO-PT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6380/obter-mac-address-da-m%C3%A1quina-cliente-da-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o)).

**Pergunta**

Estão gostaria de saber se há algum outro valor seguro que posso obter via browser e me basear para validar uma estação de trabalho, necessito desse valor para liberar e bloquear estações, e isso não tem/terá nenhuma ligação com a autenticação do sistema.

> Obs: posso obter esse valor através do *client* (JavaScript), ou server (ASP.Net MVC). Em último caso criando um Applet Java (que não é a escolha mas viável já que estações necessitariam ter o Java instalado e configurado nos browsers).
>
> > **Pelo que percebi uma alternativa 100% confiável, não parece ser possível, então gostaria de uma opção viável sem ter que utilizar extensões (Java Applets, ou Flash), utilizando puramente recursos do browser (Pode ser considerado a utilização de browser recentes IE9+).**

Comment: Os plugins de browser bancários fazem isso, acho q utilizam applets java

Comment: É por ai mesmo @Caputo, só não gostaria de ter que utilizar Applets Java.

Comment: Com JS você consegue coletar diversas informações de como a máquina está configurada. Se der sorte ninguém mais terá a mesma configuração. Por incrível que parece a chance é bem grande. https://panopticlick.eff.org/ Ele pode mudar, mas é uma outra forma de identificar.

Comment: Você não poderia criar um número único pra máquina e utilizá-lo, caso não existisse?

Comment: @bigown, isso seria facilmente mutável né? Pois o meu intuito e obter um valor e validar a maquina por um período de tempo tipo 7 dias.

Comment: É uma opção @FelipeAvelar, mas onde eu armazenaria esse valor de forma segura por um longo período de tempo?

Comment: É, mas não existe nenhuma forma real confiável, nem mesmo MAC address.

Comment: @Fernando você pode armazenar e recuperar algum dado único usando  _local storage_ com javascript, porém depende das configurações do browser. Outra solução seria criar um bookmarklet de login, como exemplifiquei nesta resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2526/70 (lembrando que um usuário malicioso poderia copiar o bookmarklet, se tiver acesso à maquina, portanto a solução só é válida se for um complemento a algo mais robusto)

Comment: Se fosse fácil identificar máquinas via Javascript as agências de publicidade não teriam que fazer [tantas gambiarras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evercookie) para monitorar as pessoas.

Comment: Já tentou usar os cookies do browser?

Comment: Não resolveria, pois eu poderia utilizar outro browser e isso ficaria invalido.

Comment: @Fernando Você mencionou estacões de trabalho. Estou supondo uma LAN, correto?

Comment: Nem sempre @OnoSendai, o que teria que fazer é uma liberação de qualquer estação de trabalho em LAN ou via Internet. To pensando em outras possibilidades, pois acho que essa não será possível, mas se tens alguma ideia para LAN, poderá ser útil.

Comment: Se você estiver em uma LAN, você tem acesso à tabela ARP, que pode identificar o MAC Address de um dado IP - o que facilita a identificação única. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6380/obter-mac-address-da-m%C3%A1quina-cliente-da-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o/6542#6542

Answer (score 5):

Não existe nenhuma forma de se pegar um valor que identifique unicamente a máquina, seja no lado do cliente por javascript ou algo do lado do servidor.

A única forma seria rodando algum programa no lado do cliente, como você mesmo citou de usar um applet feito em java.

E veja que mesmo assim não é 100% confiável, se pegar por exemplo o endereço MAC ainda existem formas de se trocar este endereço, inclusive existem placas de rede que permitem trocar ele por um valor qualquer.

Answer (score 0):

A resposta simples, não é possível.

A resposta mais elaborada é que dependendo do nivel de confiabilidade desejada você pode usar alternativas (sem uso de cookies ou qualquer dado salvo no cliente) que funcionam razoavelmente bem.

Um exemplo seria o fingerprint do browser, que é pegar dados do browser para identifica-lo futuramente, veja mais detalhes em https://wiki.mozilla.org/Fingerprinting.

Note que se algum dos componentes usado no fingerprint mudar você não vai mais reconhecer aquele cliente.